# MySQL stopped on Google Cloud Wordpress 'Click to Deploy'

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I Installed Wordpress 'Click to Deploy' on Google cloud. Everything was working fine, but after Google made a change in the system, the DB has stopped www.lucasselbach.com.br show "Erro ao estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados (Error establishing connection with Database)". I tried to open MySQL on SSH but got the error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

So I figured out that the service has stopped. Tried to restart using 
mysql --host=ipnumber --user=root --password
But didn't worked out.

Can't also open PHPMyAdmin on the specified address, it returns msg:
 #2002 Não foi possível fazer login no servidor MySQL (Could'nt make login on MySql Server).

Any hint? Suggestions?? Please help, my site is offline.

Comment: After trying again to start, it gaves me another error  ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '**ip-adresss**' (110)

Comment: what changes they made? maybe, they change some mysql server addresses?

Comment: Have you tried the following two commands?  

mysqld stop
mysql.server start

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan I am not sure, because on the console everything looks the same.

Comment: @George The command mysqld stop don't exist (gives me command not found). I tried mysql stop and returned me 2002 again.
The command mysql.server start didn't work either (command not found)

Comment: the server is Debian. Is my database located in some file that I can backup (dump) and download so I can upload to another server?

Comment: I'm not strong with servers, but think, that ther'll be some command to check mysql ports

Comment: Found the solution. MySQL was stopped (and I have no idea why it happened). Followed the steps on this page https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80031/erro-de-soquete-na-instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-mysql